# Can a macro replace a token that appears within its argument list?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to insert the size of a series of bytes within itself. If I want the size as a prefix, then this works:

```
#define COUNT(...) sizeof((uint8_t[]){__VA_ARGS__})
#define PREPEND_COUNT(...) COUNT(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__
```

```
uint8_t x[] = {PREPEND_COUNT(10, 20, 30, 40)};
//        x = {4, 10, 20, 30, 40}
```

However, I would also like to be able to insert the size elsewhere in the expansion. Reading [this page](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms) provides a bunch of tools that might make it achievable.

**Is it possible to create something along the lines of the following?**

```
uint8_t x[] = {ADD_COUNT(10, 20, THE_COUNT, 30, 40)};
//        x = {10, 20, 4, 30, 40}
```

This was my naive and unsuccessful approach:

```
#define ADD_COUNT2(THE_COUNT, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define ADD_COUNT(...) ADD_COUNT2(COUNT(__VA_ARGS__), OBSTRUCT(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: A good tool for testing this is http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/, with the command line set to `g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -E`

Comment: There's no need to use coliru to test on; one should test on his own computer and save stacked-crooked's resources.  There are also other online sites capable of showing preprocessor results, such as godbolt; its advantage is being able to flip between multiple preprocessors.  That having been said, coliru's good if you want to communicate a working example using boost preprocessor, since the site has it available in its list (but there's no reason to add `-O2` if you're using `-E`; and if you're using `-E` for gnu to just see preprocessor, you might want `-P`).  You can also just use gcc.

Comment: @HWalters: All good points, thanks. Testing on one's own computer is a little more work for someone just browsing the web. I used `g++` simply because I wasn't sure if coliru would let me invoke gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses the boost preprocessor.  There's a bit of ambiguity in your specification; I'm going to assume that `THE_COUNT` should simply be replaced with the size of the list minus one, for simplicity.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/eat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/size.hpp>

#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(F,S,...) S

#define THE_COUNT_MATCHES_THE_COUNT ,PRED_OF_COUNT
#define PRED_OF_COUNT(...) BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE((__VA_ARGS__)))

#define ELEM_OR_COUNT(z,n,data) \
    SECOND(BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n,data),_MATCHES_THE_COUNT), \
           BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n,data) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT())data

#define ADD_COUNT(...) BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE((__VA_ARGS__)),ELEM_OR_COUNT,(__VA_ARGS__))
```

This requires a bit of explaining.

The `SECOND` macro uses a technique similar to your site's `CHECK` macro in the **Detection** section.  I use this to provide defaults that can be overridden; to do so, I build a "matcher" token as the first argument.  For the things I want to expand differently, I define a matched macro (similar to `PROBE` in that section), which injects a second argument by including a comma.

In this case, I want `THE_COUNT` to expand to `PRED_OF_COUNT`, so I build a matcher token `THE_COUNT_MATCHES_THE_COUNT` (which I intend to build from `THE_COUNT_MATCHES_` plus each argument) to do that.  The data goes after the argument, so `PRED_OF_COUNT` has the right thing to count.  For the *default* case (a number) I just put that number; since I'm shoving the data afterwards, but don't want to see it, I add an eat macro (this is a bit strange; [`BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/tuple_eat.html) expands to a *macro that eats* a tuple; it's not that macro itself).

`ELEM_OR_COUNT` is a *body macro* for [`BOOST_PP_ENUM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html); see that documentation.

`ADD_COUNT` drives the mechanism.

And finally, [here's your coliru.stacked-crooked.com demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c086ad0304086d55).

Comment: Clever but understandable - thanks! As usual, it seems that I've simplified my problem a little too much. I'd also like this to work for something like `ADD_COUNT(1, 2, (COUNT + 1), 3)`, for which an approach like this wouldn't work. Does that even sound possible to you?

Comment: It's difficult to communicate the exact nuances in comments; that _exactly_ isn't possible, but something like it is.  But that something like it is too complex to be worth it.  But maybe it's worth taking a step back... if you're simply after initialized declarations, you can do something _much simpler_ (and more maintainable) by dragging pieces of the problem into the C language.  If that is the case, let me know and I'll just post it as a different answer.